# Powershell run Script in ISE full window

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Is there a was for a Powershell script to be launched from Scheduler and run full ISE window and close when done.
I am using ZeeDrive to map a SharePoint Drive but running the Script in Scheduler, it cannot see the Drive.  Yet if I open in ISE and run, it finds it fine.  What I got back from ThinkScape :

'Zee Drive needs to run in a Windows session. It is designed for end users – if it is running as a service, or “headless” i.e. no Windows session, or being accessed from a different Windows session it won’t work.
We don’t support Zee Drive running as a service or for service type workloads  – it is designed for end users working with documents'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to add your credentials to the scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of, would be to add your script to the `Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1` and then start ISE with the scheduler and your file as parameter, like this:

```
powershell_ise .\Check-Process.ps1
```

In your profile you would want to make sure, that the script only runs, when you open that file:

```
if($psISE.PowerShellTabs.Files.FullPath -eq '\\fileserver\path$\to\my\Powershell\Check-Process.ps1')
{
    & '\\fileserver\path$\to\my\Powershell\Check-Process.ps1'
}
```

But be carefull! The script runs now everytime you open it in ISE unless you use the switch `-noprofile`.

So far I did not find a way to close the ISE window with the profile script.